# NaN values from griddata (octave)

Tags: octave, nan

I generated some scattered data and want to interpolate them to a grid.
I tried to plot the convex hull (because of the description of problems from other users) but also only getting error.

```
R = 2;
r = 7;

alpha_degree = 90;
alpha_rad = alpha_degree*pi/180;

theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);

phi = linspace(0,pi,100);

[Phi,Theta] = meshgrid(phi,theta); 

x = r.*sin(Theta);
y = (R+r.*cos(Theta)).*cos(Phi);
z = (R+r.*cos(Theta)).*sin(Phi);

z(z<0) = NaN;


x_rot = x.*cos(alpha_rad) - y.*sin(alpha_rad);
y_rot = y.*cos(alpha_rad) + x.*sin(alpha_rad);
z_rot = z;


[xx,yy] = meshgrid(linspace(-5,5));

zz = griddata(x_rot,y_rot,z_rot,xx,yy);
```

---

Sorry, here are more details:
I want to have a cap of a torus, therefore I have to set the negative values to NaN with z(z<0)=NaN.
After rotation the values are as expected, I have a rotated cap.
But when I use griddata to interpolate to a regular grid, nearly every points were set to NaN ( there are only a few Points in the corners).

I don´t understand why there are so many values set to NaN by using gridata.

(Because I´m new here I can´t post images, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were xpecting: With `z(z<0) = NaN` you set roughly half of all entries to `NaN`, and after your rotation and resampling with `gridddata` again about half of your entries are `NaN` as they should be!